# ModuleNotFoundError psycopg2 when deploying in heroku even though psycopg2 is installed

Tags: django, heroku, wagtail

I migrated my website from sqlite3 to postgresql. I'm deploying my website in heroku but this error came up when I'm executing command 
`push heroku master`

```
-----> Python app detected
 !     Python has released a security update! Please consider upgrading to python-3.7.3
       Learn More: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes
-----> Installing python-3.7.2
-----> Installing pip
-----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
       Installing dependencies from Pipfile…
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
           import psycopg2 as Database
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'
       During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
           django.setup()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
           apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
           app_config.import_models()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
           self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
         File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
         File "/tmp/build_bda0f9a0e468e1cd92eba305080085ba/home/models.py", line 3, in <module>
           from wagtail.core.models import Page
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wagtail/core/models.py", line 8, in <module>
           from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
           from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
           class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
           new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
           value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
           self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
           return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
           backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
           return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
           raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
       django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

I don't know why it says import error since I already installed psycopg2 in my virtual environment. The python shell does not even throw some errors when I import it and I can run my server successfully in my local machine

[image]

In my requirements.txt file, psycopg2==2.8.3 is listed there.

My Pipfile

```
[[source]]
name = "pypi"
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true

[dev-packages]

[packages]
django = "<2.3,>=2.2"
wagtail = "<2.6,>=2.5"

[requires]
python_version = "3.7"
```

My database configuration in base.py of settings folder

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'personalsite',
    }
}
```

in production.py of my settings folder

```
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config()
```

in requirements.txt

```
psycopg2==2.8.2
beautifulsoup4==4.6.0
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.2.2
django-modelcluster==4.4
django-taggit==0.24.0
django-toolbelt==0.0.1
django-treebeard==4.3
djangorestframework==3.9.4
draftjs-exporter==2.1.6
gunicorn==19.9.0
html5lib==1.0.1
idna==2.8
Pillow==5.4.1
pytz==2019.1
requests==2.22.0
six==1.12.0
sqlparse==0.3.0
static3==0.7.0
Unidecode==1.1.0
urllib3==1.25.3
wagtail==2.5.1
webencodings==0.5.1
Willow==1.1
```

Comment: Can you share your Pipfile and settings.py file?

Comment: I just updated my post. I added the base.py and production.py in my settings folder. These are wagtail generated python files. Just like the settings.py of django.

Comment: Can you share your requirements.txt as well?

Comment: just updated bro. I think it's complete. So the maybe the problem is the Pipfile. I don't have any idea how to fix it.

Comment: It seems you are using Pipenv and confused with pip. Please try the answer below, it should work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you installed all those packages to your local Python installation and not to your virtual environment. Your **Pipfile** doesn't reflect the packages such as `psycopg2`, `dj_database_url` etc. Please install the packages to your virtual environment.

First, activate your **virtual environment**,

```
pipenv shell
```

Then install the following packages,

```
pipenv install psycopg2-binary 
pipenv install dj-database-url
```

Run `pipenv lock` to generate the appropriate `Pipfile.lock`. And try to push it to **Heroku** once again using the following command.

`push heroku master`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just executed pipenv install psycopg2-binary. It detected that it does not have a pipfile lock so its creating now. Is it normal that the locking process is very slow?

Comment: Yes, I think the issue was that you installed those packages to your local Python installation instead of the virtual environment. That's why our Pipfile wasn't updated and when you tried to push the same to Heroku, it was clueless about other packages that you used.

Comment: Okay. It now makes sense to me. I'll update you once the locking is finished. Hope I get good results.

Comment: Thanks! It was pushed successfully. You saved me! Btw, you need to replace the pipenv install install dj-database-url to pipenv install dj-database-url as it might confuse future readers.  I just noticed it few minutes ago when i tried to lock the pipfile but it failed due to the extra install that was present in the command

Comment: @jerome_mjt, the actual issue is that you have both a `Pipfile` and a `requirements.txt`. `requirements.txt` gets completely ignored if you have a `Pipfile` on Heroku. Migrate _all_ of your requirements as described in this answer and remove your `requirements.txt`.